# initDeliver -> ERRO 129 Cannot dial to 0.0.0.0:7050, because of grpc: timed out when dialing

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

What am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to familiarize myself with Hyperledger. I thought I'd run the Fabric locally and use the Marbles demo. I think the errors below explain why Marbles is unable to access the local Fabric. I deployed Blockchain on Bluemix per the Marbles' instructions and that worked correctly.

I'm following the instructions here:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/Network-setup/

Running Docker 1.12.5 on Ubuntu (4.4.0-57-generic)

Regardless of whether I run a single peer or multiple, I receive the following errors for each of the peers. It makes no difference whether I remove 7050:7050 from the vp0 peer's published ports. I'm unable to curl what I think should be a REST endpoint on 7050.

```
vp0_1  | 2017-01-08 04:46:42.723 UTC [committer] initDeliver -> ERRO 129 Cannot dial to 0.0.0.0:7050, because of grpc: timed out when dialing
vp0_1  | 2017-01-08 04:46:42.723 UTC [committer] startDeliver -> ERRO 12a Can't initiate deliver protocol [grpc: timed out when dialing]
vp1_1  | 2017-01-08 04:46:43.443 UTC [committer] initDeliver -> ERRO 12d Cannot dial to 0.0.0.0:7050, because of grpc: timed out when dialing
vp1_1  | 2017-01-08 04:46:43.443 UTC [committer] startDeliver -> ERRO 12e Can't initiate deliver protocol [grpc: timed out when dialing]
```

Here's the docker-compose.yml that I mangled from the instructions [unfamiliar with docker-compose]:

```
vp0:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
  ports:
    - "7050:7050"
    - "7051:7051"
    - "7052:7052"  
  environment:
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
  - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
  - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
  - CORE_PEER_ID=vp0
  command: peer node start
vp1:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
  environment:
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
  - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
  - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
  - CORE_PEER_ID=vp1
  - CORE_PEER_DISCOVERY_ROOTNODE=vp0:7051
  command: peer node start
  links:
  - vp0
```

Answer (score 0):

Running docker-compose up subsequently, the issue appears to no longer occur. The only changes that I'm aware of are:

-- I did some Docker house-keeping, cleaning up old containers/images
-- Time passed

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that u don't declare the orderer service
try to add

```
orderer:
    container_name: orderer
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LEDGERTYPE=ram
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_BATCHTIMEOUT=10s
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_BATCHSIZE_MAXMESSAGECOUNT=10
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_MAXWINDOWSIZE=1000
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_ORDERERTYPE=solo
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
      - ORDERER_RAMLEDGER_HISTORY_SIZE=100    
    command: orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    volumes:        
        - ./orderer-config.yaml:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/orderer.yaml 
    networks:
- bridge
```